# How to restrict access to domain alias email alias

Tags: google-app-engine, email, google-apps

I have one Google Apps account that I setup with bob@A.com

I have two companies A & B.

I have two associated domain names A.com & B.com

I have google app engine up and running for A.com.

Now I need to get Google App Engine up and running for B.com.
I need Employees of B.com to have email addresses jack@B.com & jill@B.com
I also need app engine to send emails e.g. from no-reply@B.com

However I don't want jack to have access to jack@A.com (only jack@B.com). Since Jack only works for company B.

So I assume having an email alias wont work (as that would give jack access to jack@A.com).

Apparently Google App Engine can only connect to a "Domain Alias":

[image: domain alias]

Is my only option to create an additional Google Apps Account?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to create a new Google Apps account. However for the purpose of AppEngine you can create a [one-person free Google Apps account](http://lifehacker.com/5967336/use-google-app-engine-to-get-google-apps-for-your-domain-for-free) (checked a few weeks ago and this procedure was working).

Comment: Thanks - Too bad it's only a "one-person Account". Sharing one account between the company is less than ideal. I'll have to consider paying for another Google Apps Account.

Comment: Ah - I setup no-reply as a nickname on the one-person free Google Apps account. However it won't let me accept invitations to a GAE Developer Role under the no-reply@mydomain.com email. Which means I can't send emails from no-reply@mydomain.com.